# Where does onCreate gets in Bundle type argument?

Tags: android, bundle, oncreate

i am new to the android programming and following the book Android Programming The Big Nerd Ranch 2nd Edition. So i figured that onCreate is called when an activity starts. and when it is overridden in its definition it has an argument savedInstanceState of Bundle type which stores the Current state of the activity. But where does onCreate gets its Bundle type Argument? i mean who calls the onCreate function (obviously whoever calling it must be the one providing the argument).

Answer (score 2):

The Android framework calls the lifecycle methods of the components (`Activity`, `Service`, `BroadcastReceiver` and `ContentProvider`.)  The `Bundle` is provided by the framework and can have content if the `Activity` is being re-created after something like a configuration change.